# GitHub Pages no permite redireccionamientos automáticos con Angular, muestra la página 404 de GitHub Pages

Tags: javascript, angular, github, github-pages, pwa

Creé una aplicación en Angular que automáticamente redirige a "/auth/login" cuando detecta que la sesión no ha sido iniciada.

Entonces, el problema que tengo es que si accedo directamente a la URL "usuario.github.io/app-ejemplo", la aplicación funciona bien y perfecta, pero si accedo directamente a la URL "usuario.github.io/app-ejemplo/auth/login" (o cualquier otra ruta que no sea la principal) me arroja la página 404 de GitHub.

Incluso estoy usando PWA y al instalar la aplicación en mi dispositivo Android arroja directamente la página 404 de GitHub.

Nota:

Usando el http-server, puedo instalar la aplicación en Windows y esto me muestra la aplicación, no el 404 que me sucedió con GitHub Pages.

También me di cuenta de que si uso Lighthouse y hago una prueba usando el http-server, también arroja un 404 al ejecutar la prueba.

Comment: me paso algo parecido, una ves logeados se redirige a otro HTML en local me funcionaba pero no en GitHub, mi problema era que al entrar a  "usuario.github.io/app-ejemplo" todo estaba normal, pero para redirigir a  "usuario.github.io/app-ejemplo/pagina_principal" este no me mandaba a ese lugar sino a "usuario.github.io/pagina_principal" y la pues la url no tenia "app-ejemplo" asi que salía 404, lo arregle desplegando en Netlify

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la respuesta en StackOverflow en ingles.

[Solución a problema de 404 en rutas relativas en GitHub Pages con Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74980788/17101360)

Adicionalmente tuve que añadir unos cambios en mi manifest.webmanifest porque GitHub Pages estaba buscando el manifest a nivel de mi usuario de Github y no del proyecto:

```
...
"start_url": "./"
...
```

Y tambien en el index.html:

```html
...

<link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.webmanifest">
...
```